# What type of backend to use for iOS app

Tags: mysql, sqlite, swift, server, backend

I've created an app for iOS using Swift that is essentially a Latin dictionary. Users have the ability to create new words that aren't included in the app. The data is stored locally in the app's document directory in two SQLite databases. The first one holds the words that ship with the app. The second holds the words that are created by the user.

I want to have each word created by the user uploaded to a server at runtime and added to a master database of words. That server would then compare each incoming entry to [William Whitaker's Words](http://archives.nd.edu/words.html) to see if it is in fact a valid Latin word and then to see if it is already in the master database. If it is valid and not already in the master DB, then the word would be added.
After every new entry to the master database, the server would generate a new SQLite database that includes the new word. Every time the app runs it will check for a newer version of the StandardData.sqlite file and if there is one, it is downloaded. Words that are common to the Standard library and the user's custom library would then be deleted from the custom library to prevent duplicates.

Over time a large library of Latin words would be created without me having to manually enter them in from a dictionary.

I'm somewhat familiar with MySQL (When using it with MySQL workbench) but beyond that I'm mostly unfamiliar with today's web programming tools: HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, Java, Ruby, Rails, PHP, etc. My budget is 0$ and ideally I would like to host the server on my own hardware. What is the best way to add a backend to my app?

Comment: This is *incredibly* subjective (and product recommendation questions are off-topic for Stackoverflow) but use something you're familiar with if you can. Such as Swift.

Comment: Swift is a programming language for the cocoa platform and is not a backend solution. But I tend to agree with your point about this being subjective, I just didn't know where this question belonged

Comment: https://github.com/glock45/swifter - HTTP server written in Swift. There's the foundation of a backend solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question of opinion, so I'm not sure this is the best forum.  However you have several options, including some that could be completely free.

Rails and PHP as you have mentioned can be used to create a backend using mysql as the data layer.  If you are new to both of those languages, you might look at Python using one of the many frameworks for it.  If your app is completely iOS based, you might also look into using CloudKit, which is free up to certain sizes (which it sounds like you could easily stay below).  The advantage of CloudKit would be that you don't even have to host the service on your own hardware.  There are a few other similar options as well, included Firebase and Parse which both have free tiers that likely would provide all the storage you need.

With any of these three, you'd be using the API in swift in your iOS project, and not having to learn a new language.

Comment: Those all sound like good options for an iOS based backend. I guess I'm concerned with being able to compare incoming data to that website linked above, I think the webpage it returns can be easily parsed but that requires a server side script which not all platforms are suited for. Cloud Kit sounds like the best option but it would mean moving away from sql. Your answer was very informative