# How to call this shell script to convert mysqldump to SQLite compatible syntax

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, sqlite, shell

I need to autonomously convert mysqldump files (.sql file) to SQLite compatible .sql files. I found this [script](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776) on github which is supposed to be able to do this. If I had an unmodified .sql file from MySQL called test.sql whose database's name was test and the script mysql2sqlite.sh in a directory, how would I call it.

The script says in the comments how to call it. I believe my scenario matches the first one titled usage because I already have the mysqldump file.

```
# Usage: $ ./mysql2sqlite mysqldump-opts db-name | sqlite3 database.sqlite
# Example: $ ./mysql2sqlite --no-data -u root -pMySecretPassWord myDbase | sqlite3 database.sqlite
```

I read in the comments on the github page to change the scripts permissions with `chmod +x mysql2sqlite.sh` so navigated to the directory with the sql and the script and did that.
Then I tried:

`pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ./mysql2sqlite.sh test.sql test | sqlite3 database.sqlite`

It failed with the error: `-bash: ./mysql2sqlite.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

I then read online that to call an .sh file you type `sh myShellFile.sh`

So I tried `sh mysql2sqlite.sh test.sql test | sqlite3 database.sqlite`
and got back:

```
: not founde.sh: 2: mysql2sqlite.sh:
: not founde.sh: 5: mysql2sqlite.sh:
: not founde.sh: 8: mysql2sqlite.sh:
: not founde.sh: 11: mysql2sqlite.sh:
: not founde.sh: 13: mysql2sqlite.sh:
: not founde.sh: 14: mysql2sqlite.sh:
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'pi'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
: not founde.sh: 15: mysql2sqlite.sh:
```

It appears that its trying to connect to a server rather than reading the mysqldump file that I provided. What is the proper way to call this script. I have some experience with Linux and no experience with unix shells.

It may be of some use to read the background of my [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747242/what-type-of-backend-to-use-for-ios-app)

EDIT: After editing the first line of the script running it again produces the error `Error: near line 4: near "Insert": syntax error`

Here is the sqldump I'm trying to process:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Feb 28, 2015 at 06:00 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.17
-- PHP Version: 5.5.12

SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `testtable`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testtable` (
  `FirstName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `testtable`
--

INSERT INTO `testtable` (`FirstName`, `LastName`) VALUES
('', ''),
('Josh', 'Kallus'),
('', ''),
('Josh', 'Kallus');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: `/bin/sh^M`: Your script has Windows-line endings (/r/n). The first line (shebang) tells which program should be used for running the script.
Does it work better after `sed -i 's/^M//' mysql2sqlite` (you should enter ^M as ctrl-v ctrl-m), or could you remove the ^M with dos2unix or an editor?

Comment: Notepad++ has a line ending converter, I'll try that

Comment: After doing that I ran it again with this output:` mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'pi'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect memory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the comments in the script. The script is expecting mysql dump options followed by the dbname (not a dump file). If you look at the first line of code you will see how it works.

```
mysqldump  --compatible=ansi --default-character-set=utf8 --compatible=ansi --skip-extended-insert --compact  "$@" | \
```

The script is expecting the output MySQL data to be using the parameters it also passes, so the best method is probably to use the script as intended.

```
mysql2sqlite.sh -h my.host.com --single-transaction -umyuser -p mydb | sqlite3 database.sqlite
```

If you can only do this from an existing dump file, then you could change that first mysqldump line in the code to this

```
cat $@ | \
```

Then you could do this

```
mysql2sqlite.sh test.sql | sqlite3 database.sqlite
```

Keep in mind that this script is not a silver bullet, you may run into other incompatibility issues. You may be able to resolve them by directly editing the dump file itself. Good luck.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html

Edit: As I originally stated, this script is not a magic bullet and you may have to edit your dump to make it work (best compatibility coming from using it's built in dump function) I've edited your script to what you see below and it should work.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Feb 28, 2015 at 06:00 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.17
-- PHP Version: 5.5.12

SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `testtable`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testtable` (
  `FirstName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(30) NOT NULL
);

--
-- Dumping data for table `testtable`
--

INSERT INTO `testtable` (`FirstName`, `LastName`) VALUES('', ''),('Josh', 'Kallus'),('', ''),('Josh', 'Kallus');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: My database is very simple. Just 4 tables, only strings and ints. This should work for me I think.

Comment: Sounds like it. Change that line and you should be in business.

Comment: That didn't quite solve it. I posted the sqldump so that the problem might be identified.

Comment: That gave an error: SQL error: unrecognized token: "`" If this requires manually editing the sql file then this won't work. I could potentially be doing this hundreds of times per day which isn't feasible. Thanks for your help, but this probably should never have been attempted. I'l just have to find a different workflow. If you would like to know more about why this has to be automated then check out the linked [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747242/what-type-of-backend-to-use-for-ios-app)

Comment: The script should work if you use it as intended and I believe the answer is correct for your script. Would appreciate if you marked it as so (for my efforts). Thanks.